# Stop receiving GitHub notifications

Tags: github, account-management, notifications

I starred the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) project a while ago. I unstarred it recently. For some reason I get notifications (on my account page and via email). I'm not sure why I started getting issue notifications since I had it set to "only ones I participate in". I'd like to stop receiving them, so I set it to "ignore". Now I no longer receive them on my account page, but I still get email notifications. I have not created or commented on any issues on this project.

[image]

Like the one below, the emails are all from `notifications@github.com`, with a generated reply-to address.

Is there a way to reply back with unsubscribe?

[image]

I'm aware I can mark it as spam/filter the emails, but I'd prefer to fix the problem at the source, or report a bug if needed.

So, what am I missing... or did I stumble on a bug?

### EDIT:

So, I checked out a couple emails and clicked on the "View it on GitHub" links in each. I haven't commented nor am I @mentioned, but I receive these emails (for new issues even) despite the ignore setting mentioned and shown above.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are probably subscribed to the issues you get notifications from.

I'd suggest you to click the "view it on GitHub" link and scroll to the bottom.

You will see a button there to unsubscribe from the thread/issue:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and have added more information above. It looks like I could try to `ignore` each thread... but I don't know if that will work, and I shouldn't have to to begin with.

Comment: I have a similar problem on various repos ...

Comment: The problem with this is that every time ANYONE posts everyone else starts getting notifications for every issue they make any comment on or create. It gets very SPAMMY very quickly. The email options under Settings doesn't help either. The least spammy option is the Subscribed one we're discussing here.